# Unavailable images on order email from private website

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, email-templates, password

I have a Magento 1.9 installation that uses multiple stores and one of them is password protected, using **.htaccess** and **.htpasswd**. When an order is placed on the password protected website, the order email images don't show. Instead, they are replaced by links (as shown below) [image]

The link points to my private website and I know that the problem is that my email provider (gmail in my case) can't access the files because accessing the url requires a password. I know what the problem is, but I am wondering what would be the cleanest solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the new Apache  statement feature:

```
<If "!(%{REQUEST_URI} -strmatch '*media*') && (%{HTTP_HOST} == 'website-to-protect.com')">
(Deny access with password protection)
</If>
```